# How to integrate to an external platform API in PHP?

Tags: php, api

My approach is to fetch the GetUser API
Platform api url is http://xxxxxx.com/api/api.aspx
GetUser API requires:

1. method -> "GetUser"
2. SecretKey-> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3. Time -> 20220627102845
4. Username -> xxxxxxxxxx

As I have followed from the API document:
I have created an encryption class DES for urlencoded variable of an encrypted key (which in this case, our Encryptkey is xxxxxxxx) 'q'.
I have also created an MD5 hashed string, 's', with the following format:
str + md5key(xxxxxxx) + Time + SecretKey

For example: q=j4tjorjwarfj3trwise0safrwg2wt4awari0fwjfeoh&s=1234567890abcdef

In order to fetch, as the document stated, I need to POST data with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded to get the XML result from the API, which I also have done
The problem:
I keep getting a 403 Forbidden Page from the API with an 'http' request

Below is my code:

```
<?php

class DES
{
    var $key;
    var $iv;
    function DES( $key, $iv=0 ) {
        $this->key = $key;
        if( $iv == 0 ) {
            $this->iv = $key;
        } else {
            $this->iv = $iv;
        }
    }
 
    function encrypt($str) {
        
        return base64_encode( openssl_encrypt($str, 'DES-CBC', $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $this->iv  ) );
    }
 
}

    $method = "GetUser";

    // DES encrypt the Query String
    $str = "method=".$method."&Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Time=20220627102845&Username=xxxxxxxxx"; 
    $key = "xxxxxxx";
    $crypt = new DES($key);
    $mstr = $crypt->encrypt($str);
    $q = urlencode($mstr);

    // Build an MD5 hash
    $str="method=".$method."&Key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Time=20220627102845&Username=xxxxxxxx";
    $md5key = "xxxxxxxx"; 
    $Time = "20220627102845"; //DV
    $SecretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
    $PreMD5Str = $str . $md5key . $Time . $SecretKey;
    $s = md5($PreMD5Str);

    
    // Setup cURL
    $curl = curl_init( 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/api.aspx');


    // Turn off Mandatery SSL checker
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // Gather the param
    $paramData = "q=".$q."&s=".$s;
    echo $paramData;

    // Configure the url session based on the type of request
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Decide that this is a POST reques
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Convert the request data to a json data
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($paramData));

    // Set the API headers 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]);

    // Run url
    $run = curl_exec($curl);

    // Error checker
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    if($error){
        die('Curl return some errors..'. $error);
    }

    // Close curl session
    curl_close($curl);

    var_dump($run);

?>
```

Comment: I would use GuzzleClient instead of curl.

Comment: _"In order to fetch, as the document stated, I need to POST data with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"_ - but that's not what you are sending; you explicitly encoded your parameters as JSON.